# Where did the outputstream go when no method are set?

Tags: java, php, json, http

So basicly I have some Java code making an HTTPURLConnection on an ip an send json in the output stream and I suppose to catch it on my php server.
The problem here is that I can modify the java code, and some other server in python already do what I'm suppose to done so I assume taht it is possible.

The Json object just get writen on the OutputStream of the connection ; connection is parameter like this :

```
connection.setDoInput(true)
connection.setDoOutput(true)
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "Application/JSON");
```

and I can find my object either in the $_GET or the $_POST... where did he go it seem like no one else have the stupid idear to not use setRequestMethod.

Comment: can use the method "$_REQUEST"  instead of post or 
file_get_contents('php://input')); php_input dumps everything requested from cient side , headers and body then you can extract only body then parse it to variables , you

Comment: Thank you. I have everting i need in  file_get_contents('php://input')). Please @K3rnel31 post an aswer so I can validate it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the method `"$_REQUEST"` instead of post or

```
file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

php_input dumps everything requested from cient side , headers and body then you can extract only body then parse it to variables